# Scikit-learn - Getting NAN value while measuring accuracy.

Tags: python

I am classifying positive and negative sentiment on sample data. I used the following code snippet.

Everything looks OK until line 20 where it print expected predictions.

But when i try to measure the accuracy using metrics , it gave me "NAN" value. Can you please review my codes and help me find out the issue.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import  MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer  
from sklearn import metrics
import csv

# Read in the training data.
with open("/Users/max/train.csv", 'r') as file:
  reviews = list(csv.reader(file))

with open("/Users/max/test.csv",'r') as file:
    test_reviews = list(csv.reader(file))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
train_features = vectorizer.fit_transform([review[0] for review in reviews])
test_features = vectorizer.transform([test_review[0] for test_review in test_reviews])

nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(train_features, [int(review[1]) for review in reviews])

predictions = nb.predict(test_features)
print("prediction : {0}".format(predictions))

actual = [int(r[1]) for r in test_reviews]
fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(actual, predictions, pos_label=1) 
print("Multinomial naive bayes AUC: {0}".format(metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)))
```

Sample datasets are in this format

```
i like google , 1
i dont really like microsoft , -1
```

Here is the output in console

```
prediction : [1 -1]
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py:496: UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless UndefinedMetricWarning)
Multinomial naive bayes AUC: nan
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `roc_auc_score` instead? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

Comment: @Dair , seems like it works. What is difference between them?

Comment: I don't know, but the documentation points it out as an alternative.

Comment: The problem is that auc is used when predicting binary outbomes.  If your response variable is binary then perhaps you should be using `BernoulliNB` instead of `MultinomialNB` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html

Answer (score 2):

probability you don't have any true positive instance in your data.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: I think the previous answer is good enough and provides precise explanation. Error is occurred since there are no true positive values!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I mistakenly concatenated `X_train` and `y_train` and used this dataframe as my `X_train`. Basically, the `X_train` had `y_train` in it as the last column, which shouldn't be the case.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man. Your tip reminded me to check the data! My cross-validation wasn't shuffling the data.